# Attractors and stability.

Tags: general-topology, chaos-theory

[image]

Does anyone who studied chaos get this?

I get everything preceding the red box, but I don't understand how it makes x* an attractor.

The notes we have don't explain the theory very well, nor wikipedia.

Thank you.

For anyone who can't read the image, he's my latex attempt:

Let $f(x^*)=x^*$ and $f$ be smooth at $x^*$

Let $x_t=x^*+\delta_t:    |\delta_t|<<1$

Expand $f$ in Taylor series at $x^*$

$x_{t+1}=f(x_t)=f(x^*+\delta_t)=f(x^*)+f'(x^*)\delta_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(x^*)\delta_t^2+O(\delta_t^3$

$\delta_{t+1}+x^*=x^*+f'(x^*)\delta_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(x^*)\delta_t^2+O(\delta_t^3)$

This gives

$\delta_{t+1}=f'(x^*)\delta_t+O(\delta_t^2)$

and so $x^*$ is an attractor if $|f'(x^*)|<1$

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that as long as $|f^\prime(x^*)|<1$, then
$|\delta_{t+1}|$<$|\delta_t|$.  This means that with each step, your perturbation is smaller than it was in the previous step.  Therefore your solution is always approaching $x^*$, and so $x^*$ is an attractor.  (Caveat: I'm really just an interested amateur in chaos theory.)

Comment: http://images.4chan.org/sci/src/1366829050771.png

I have a question about this image now.

Firstly, does that symbol mean "Greater than or less than"? And how to the diagrams to the right represent what is going on?

What I've understood from this is that only the 4th case gives an attractor.

Comment: Sorry, can't see the image.  Firewall problem.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/K3xIl1Y.png

Here you go buddy.

Comment: Never mind. 19 hours later and I've now figured it out!

For even $k$, in the case of $f^k(x)>0$ if $x_{t}<x^*$, then $\delta_t$ is negative, and we have an attractor, but it repels otherwise.

Thanks for your time anyway man.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I get it now.

Taking any point within distance $\delta$ of $x^*$, it is shown that this distance $\delta$ grows smaller with time if $|f'(x^*)|<1$. This shows that $x^*$ attracts nearby points and is therefore an attractor.